# How to elegantly map multiple functions over a matrix?

Tags: matrix, functional-style, map, pure-function

```
plus     = Map[Plus[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &,     Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}];
subtract = Map[Subtract[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}];
times    = Map[Times[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &,    Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}];
divide   = Map[Divide[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &,   Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}];
ops = {plus, subtract, times, divide};
```

The first four statements differ only by the functions they perform. Therefore, I want to combine them together for a better reusability.

> How can I compactly combine the five statements into a single one, something like

```
  ops = ({plus, subtract, times, divide} = (possibly some code here...), Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}] (possibly some code here);?
```

Comment: Look into `Through`... but there are other means vs mapping that are "prettier" to get your results

Comment: @ciao Thanks. How should I combine `Through` with `Map` and `Table`? My trials produce strange results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You very nearly had it. What you need, instead of `Map[]`, is `Apply[]`. This can then be combined with `Map[]`, like so:

```
mat = Table[{i, j}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
Apply[#, mat, {2}] & /@ {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}
```

Comment: (This *Mathematica Gedanken Version* is quite taxing to use!)

Comment: I wonder what do you do when the garbage collector starts swinging

Comment: Why, I step out and hand him my filled-up trash bag, of course.

Answer (score 10):

This is really a natural fit for [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
t = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];

Outer[Apply, {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}, t, 2]

(*
==> {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 1/2}, {2, 1}}}
*)
```

Comment: +1. Great to be reminded for what use case Outer was conceived of.

Comment: @gwr Thanks - I guess one can recognize that `Outer` is tailored for this scenario, from the fact that no `#` and `&` appears in this code...

Answer (score 5):

You might just map the `Map`s

```
ops = {plus, subtract, times, divide} = 
 Function[op, Map[op[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], {2}]] /@ 
 {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}
```

> ```
> {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 1/2}, {2, 1}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If `Table` is part of your actual operation you will be served by learning [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[#, {2, 2}] & /@ {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}
```

> ```
> {
>  {{2, 3}, {3, 4}},
>  {{0, -1}, {1, 0}},
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 4}},
>  {{1, 1/2}, {2, 1}}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) to do this:

```
mytable = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
Replace[mytable, List[a_, b_] -> #[a, b], {-2}] & /@ {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}
```

> `{{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 1/2}, {2, 1}}}`